# Are there any differences with longer duration of meditation?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Will I see any difference if I choose 1 hour or any other duration for meditation?

I know that during the meditation some potions and bombs will be automatically refilled. Is there any difference other then the elapsed time?

And is it more dangerous to meditate longer, maybe because of wild animals or bandits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference if you only need to replenish health or potions. The main reason to meditate for longer periods is if a quest requires you to be at a place during a specific time period, or if you're waiting for merchants to restock or replenish gold.

I've finished the game once, and played a second one for a while now. I've never been attacked during meditation, and haven't heard about this at all. So I'm reasonably sure that meditation is safe.

Comment: the game basically pauses when your meditating. I've meditated in the middle of conversations with people. I don't think the world moves at all while meditating.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between longer or shorter meditation besides the elapsed time.

Comment: But it is possible to get attacked while meditate in the woods so longer meditation would increase the chance of being attacked

Comment: You cannot be attacked while meditating.

Comment: Well i thought you can however could you proof that?

Comment: from my experience you don't get attacked, because meditation only works if there's no hostile within aggro range. the moment a creature gets within aggro range meditation aborts and u have to move away to continue meditation or kill it.

Comment: @rwank so it's possible that meditation aborts e.g. if monsters respawn nearby?

Comment: that is a possibility. from my experience, i had this issue when i rested before engaging a noonwraith, i waited to get to the right time of day to engage it and it moved within aggro range before i reached the time, canceling my meditation. i had to move further away to meditate again.

Comment: that's what my experience say too, had something like this with wolves before

Comment: You can definitely be attacked while meditating. It's happened to me when I meditated in the woods right after killing some monsters. If you meditate in a safe part of the woods where monsters don't spawn, I bet that's just fine.

Comment: You can never be attacked **while** meditating since it will interrupt the process before you get attacked.